# sed overwrites output with another part of replacement pattern

Tags: sed

I would like to reorder some events from my .ics calendar. However, `sed` somehow for some reason overwrites some parts of the output.

```
# original text
$ cat test
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20151230
SUMMARY:Blanka Palakova
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DURATION:P1D
END:VEVENT

# command which should work
$ /bin/sed -r 's/^(SUMMARY:)(.*) (.*)$/\1\3, \2/g' test
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20151230
, BlankaPalakova
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DURATION:P1D
END:VEVENT

# desired output
$ cat test
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20151230
SUMMARY:Palakova, Blanka
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DURATION:P1D
END:VEVENT
```

Also, I would like this to be the last occurance of the space before enf of line, for some of my events have middle names, too.

---

`sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

`GNU bash, version 4.3.39(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The source of the problem

The problem is in the file's line-endings, not the command.

When I run your command, the output is correct:

```
$ /bin/sed -r 's/^(SUMMARY:)(.*) (.*)$/\1\3, \2/g' test
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20151230
SUMMARY:Palakova, Blanka
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DURATION:P1D
END:VEVENT
```

If I convert your input file to DOS/Windows line-endings, `\r\n`, then the same  problem that you experienced occurs:

```
$ unix2dos <test >test.dos
$ /bin/sed -r 's/^(SUMMARY:)(.*) (.*)$/\1\3, \2/g' test.dos
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20151230
, BlankaPalakova
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DURATION:P1D
END:VEVENT
```

What happened is that the `\r` from the end of the line is included in group 3, `\3`, and placed in the middle of the line.  `\r` means carriage return (without jumping to the next line).  That is what happens.  The cursor ("carriage") returns to the start of the line and the `, Blanka` overwrites what had been there.

#### Solutions

One solution is to convert the input file to unix line-endings, `\n`, with dos2unix or other utility.

Another solution is to make the sed command tolerant of DOS-Windows line-endings:

```
$ /bin/sed -r 's/^(SUMMARY:)(.*) ([^\r]*)/\1\3, \2/g' test.dos
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20151230
SUMMARY:Palakova, Blanka
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DURATION:P1D
END:VEVENT
```

Since regular expressions in sed are *greedy*, the expression `([^\r]*)` will match either to the end of the line or to the first `\r`, whichever comes first.

Comment: Perfect! … I have totally forgotten about `\r`. Thank you :).